# How can I wrap a DIV around Sub-Menu in WordPress - only in First-Level?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, menu

I built my WordPress Menu with an Extended Walker Menu.
I need around the FIRST-Level of the Submenus of a DIV Wrapped. This is already working. Here is my Code:

```
class SH_Child_Only_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

     function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"submenu\"><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }

     function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n<span class=\"subtoggle\"></span></div>\n";
    }
```

But here i get this DIV wrappped around every Sub-Menu, also in deeper Levels.

**I need it just this way:**

First Level: Main Menu

Second Level: Sub-Menu (with DIV)

Third Level: Sub-Menu (without DIV)

How can i achieve this with the Extended Walker Menu. I dont want to use jQuery or any JavaScript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering this myself today when I ran into this question. I tend to look for quick solutions before doing my own coding, but after thinking about it for a moment, it's a simple solution.

```
class SH_Child_Only_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

 function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    if($depth == 0){
        $output .= "\n$indent<div class=\"submenu\"><ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }else{
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";   
    }
}

 function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    if($depth == 0){
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n<span class=\"subtoggle\"></span></div>\n";
    }else{
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n\n";
    }
}
```

$depth is what level you're on, it's zero indexed, so it starts at 0. If $depth 0 isn't what you need, just change what number you're checking against.

My example might not be the exact markup you need, but hopefully this illustrates how to go about it.